# How do I align a widget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I cannot move the widget into the layout (QGridLayout). You need to move the "label shift" to the other widgets. That they were close. How can I do that?

[image]

```
QLabel * label_answer = new QLabel(this);
label_answer->setText("label_shift");
label_answer->setFont(params_font);
label_answer->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("label_answer_%1").arg(count-1));
lay->addWidget(main_label, i,0, Qt::AlignLeft);
lay->addWidget(box_input_value, i, 1, Qt::AlignLeft);
lay->addWidget(label_answer, i, 2, Qt::AlignLeft); // label_shift
```

Comment: `label_answer` can't be moved more to the left as it is placed into the 2nd column and the 1st column is stretched to the size of a SpinBox in the second row

Answer (score 1):

You could add a extra column to the gridlayout, have the spinbox span 2 columns, which would mean the space needed in the label row is after the label, instead of before it